# Qlik view- Hide formulas to customer

Tags: security, hide, qlikview

my company wants to sell our project developed on qlik view to a customer that already has a Qlik view server but we would like to hide all formulas.
Is it possible to do it without managing access for specific users?
For instance, I know that the access to the script section can be managed with a password.
Is there something similar for objects properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can "lock" the expressions like the load script.

Even if you:

- load the calculations as variables in the hidden script - visible in the  `Variable Overview` window.
- load the calculations as separate table inside the data model - visible in objects (like listbox, table box etc.) and data model viewer

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that seems to work for my purpose:
-I have removed the flag from "access to object properties" from security tab
-I have created an hidden script protected with a password
-I have put the following code in the script:

```
Section Access;

LOAD * INLINE [
ACCESS, NTNAME
ADMIN, MickeyMouse
USER, *
];

Section Application;
```

In this way only MickeeyMouse user can access and revert back the applied security options and no one know it because the code is in the hidden script